# can I use my own variable in .muttrc config

Tags: email, mutt

I am using mutt,

in my config I have:

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://$my_address@000.000.000.000:25/"
set folder = imap://000.000.000.000:143
```

where 000.000.000.000 is the ip of my server (or could ofc be replaced by domain)

I am looking to replace to IP hardcoded inside these values by a variable.

So I tried the following but it didn't work as ip is not something mutt can recognize.

```
set ip="000.00.00.000"
set smtp_url = "smtp://$my_address@$ip:25/"
set folder = imap://$ip:143
```

Is there anyway to achieve this without throwing mutt off when parsing the config file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The man page on the .muttrc file tells us that we can use environment variables. Try `man muttrc | less -penvironment` to verify this.
So using a variable such as $ip inside .muttrc should work. However you should set this variable outside the .muttrc file. You could do this while starting mutt like this: `ip=000.000.000.000 mutt` or you could write a small wrapper shell script like this: put the lines below in a file called mymutt.sh

ip=000.000.000.000
mutt

Then execute this file with `bash mymutt.sh` (or make the file executable via chmod)

Answer (score 1):

Mutt allows setting custom variables which must begin with the prefix "my_", so you can do

```
set my_ip="000.00.00.000"
set smtp_url = "smtp://$my_address@$my_ip:25/"
set folder = imap://$my_ip:143
```

See ["User-defined variables" in the docs](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#set-myvar).